# Query keeps giving error Access '13

Tags: ms-access

I have this query and it isnt working correctly, but my knowledge says it should be!

**ERD:**
[image]

**Table 'Meetingen':**
[image]

**Table 'Patienten':**
[image]

**The query I have:**

[image]

**With the result by running:**
[image]

So, the strange thing here is; datum(date) BETWEEN 5/1/2015 AND 5/31/2015 should only give the persons from table 'meetingen' where the date is in May.
But the result is, 'adres', 'postcode' and 'patientnr' from all 'Patienten'.
Tryed everything... Does someone sees it?

**EDIT**
Made one stupid mistake, m.patientnr = m.patientnr, already changed to p.patientnr = m.patientnr witch now gives the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BETWEEN 5/1/2015 AND 5/31/2015 should only give the persons from table 'meetingen' where the date is in May

That appears to be the case in the results.  All of those dates are either `5/1/2015` or `5/30/2015`, which is in the selected range.

> But the result is, 'adres', 'postcode' and 'patientnr' from all 'Patienten'.

Yes, because those columns are on that table.  Where else would you expect them to come from?  If the columns existed on both tables then the query would result in an error indicating that it couldn't determine which column you were referring to.  But since those columns are on only one table, the query can discern what to show and it shows you the results from that table.

Also, note:

```
WHERE m.patientNr = m.patientNr
```

This condition will *always* be true.  Did you mean to do this instead?

```
WHERE m.patientNr = p.patientNr
```

You may want to investigate `JOIN` syntax to make table joins more explicit, rather than doing it in a `WHERE` clause.  Separating the joins from the filters makes the intent more clear and errors easier to find.

Comment: @JimVercoelen: Well, are the types the same?

Comment: @Jim, field types are not the same. As your table screenshots show, in Meetingen, `patientNr` has values left justified (suggesting text type) and in the table Patienten, `patientNR` has values right justified (suggesting number type). Confirm this in table design view.

Answer (score 1):

It is not date but datum:

```
Where ...
And datum Between #5/1/2015# And #5/31/2015#
```

Comment: Then either `m.patientNr` or `p.patientNr` has Null values.